# How to compile object inside a string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this string:

```
const fullname = "my name is ${param.name}"
```

and this object:

```
const param = {
  name: 'foo'
};
```

Is there a way to "compile" the string with the object in typescript/javascript?

Why? I want to separate the data from the schema (string).

Both are in separate files so I can't just do: `my name is ${param.name}`.

I have a function that takes the string and the object and make the output. but there is something like this exist?

The result I expect is:

```
`my name is foo`
```

Comment: Could you share a codebase repo link or repl or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer (one line of code) - yes - it's possible

```
console.log(new Function('obj', 'return "hello " + obj.name')({ name: 'jackob' }))
```

Let's break it down to better understand what's happaned:

```
new Function('obj', 'return "hello " + obj.name')
```

This will create a new function that accepts a single parameter (as the name implies we are expecting an object). The function body is handling the object and concat it into a string (very similar to what you tried to do)

In order to run it we can use it as an anonymous function or create a reference (e.g. function delegation)

```
const func = new Function('obj', 'return "hello " + obj.name')

func({ name: 'jackob' }) // here we call the function with a static object as parameter
```

Because the function return a value (a compiled string) we can get the returned value

```
const value = func({ name: 'jackob' })
console.log(value)
```

**And one last technical note:** if you feel that you are going to compile expressions - I recommend `JSONata` (here's a specific [link](http://docs.jsonata.org/expressions) to your use-case). It's a great project that unifies your operations over `json objects` and will help you to get more support during development and in future releases.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a template string:
You can use the following syntax:

```
`my name is ${param.name}`
```

Comment: Further information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I edit my question.